# Why is there STILL no sql shortcut to include/not include null values in a where condition?

Tags: sql

```
 select 1 where somevalue = '' or somevalue is null from sometable
```

I completely understand the reasoning behind *why* I have to have two separate conditions.  What baffles my mind is why after so many years there still isn't a standard shortcut notation for this.

I can see why various dbms implementations don't offer a shortcut since it isn't necessary and doing so would make your sql that much less portable, but considering the usefulness of such a shortcut across all dbms's I can't comprehend why the powers that be haven't added a shortcut to do this into the sql specifications.

My question:  Is there actually a legitimate reason and if so what is it?

Comment: while i can see your point, i'd guess that part of it is that the presence of an empty something is fundamentally different than the absence of that something?

Comment: Uh, the function coalesce() solves the problem.  Why is this not sufficient?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ... coalesce() will achieve what he wants, but you could just as easily use coalesce to convert NULL to 'Chester Copperpot'. the way i'm reading the question is that the OP is looking for a SQL construct which by definition logically treats empty and null as the same for the purposes of comparison/calculation/etc

Comment: Well you can do it yourself (except in oracle where you don't need to) by either `where COALESCE (somevalue,'') = '' ` of by creating a UDF NulOrEmpty and then you call it `WHERE NulOrEmpty(someValue)`. Typically software tool companies don't implement something that you can easily implement yourself. Since designing and testing and documenting features uses resources and they spend it on things that you can't do easily.

Comment: Don't worry, almost all language follows the same convention, i.e. empty string is different from null. e.g C# `null` vs `""`

Comment: @MichaelBuen Actually, C# provides a great shortcut for dealing with this that I use all the time: "If xyz ?? "" == "" then ..."

Comment: @ConradFrix I gave you +1 for pointing out that it can be done in a udf, however you are absolutely wrong about saying that software companies don't implenet something that you can easily implement yourself.  Where do you think C++ got it's name from?  They do it all the time because their job is to make you more productive.

Comment: If ANSI SQL could adopt C#'s `??`, it will be indeed a shortcut, precluding the need for COALESCE/ISNULL. The problem with COALESCE or ISNULL (or any expression for that matter) is they are not utilizing index (unless you are using Postgresql index on expression, or using Sql Server's persisted formula). If there's a first class operator blurring the distinction between null and empty string, the database can translate it to an optimized condition that uses index

Comment: @MichaelBuen I think that's exactly what they should do.  Would make a lot of code more concise and easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just

```
select * from table where isnull(columnname,'')=''
```

or if you are worried about ' ' values then you would use ltrim and/or rtrim.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s I thought that's what you were here for ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm used to working in Oracle, where the empty string *is* NULL, but wouldn't this work?

```
SELECT 1 FROM sometable WHERE COALESCE( somevalue, '' ) = ''
```

Comment: I find your SQL pretty funny. `NVL` is an oracle thing and its the only place this idea [wouldn't work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec866/1) because as you said `''` is null in oracle

Comment: Oh yeah, oops. But COALESCE should work just as well, as Gorgon Linoff suggested above.

Comment: Except of course in Oracle because that's like  `COALESCE( somevalue, '' ) = NULL` which always returns false

Comment: Yes, but clearly the OP isn't using Oracle or this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Never knew that an empty string and null were equivalent in Oracle.  I'm not sure if I like that or not.  On the one hand it reduces the usefulness of NULL in regards to its ability to create another meaningful value your field can have, but on the other hand it would prevent the misuse of it for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue.  The only strangeness is caused by Oracle's not following the standard in making NULL the same as ''.

It is pretty easy to to this:    `coalesce(columnname,'')=''`

On MS SQL Server you can also use this:   `isnull(columnname,'')=''`

But be aware it is a MS only function.